# Can we read dbisam .dat files through vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dbisam

I am using a 3rd party account software which uses a dbisam database and have tables with .dat extension.

is there any way to read dbisam tables in vb.net?

I am getting quite difficult to read dbisam in visual basic, is there any guide of tip available, please provide your input.

Here is the code I tried but nothing is working

Dim contents As New StringBuilder()
        Dim enc As Encoding = New ASCIIEncoding()

```
    'flDatFile is the source of .dat file

    Using fStream As FileStream = New FileStream(flDatFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

        ' The maximum bytes to read.
        Dim toRead As Int32 = 1024000 ' 1Kb

        ' The buffer for read bytes.
        Dim buffer(toRead - 1) As Byte

        ' The number of bytes that have been read.
        Dim read As Int32 = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, toRead)

        ' While there is any data that has been read
        Do While read > 0

            ' Get the string from the byte array.
            MsgBox(enc.GetString(buffer, 0, read))

            ' Read next batch of data into the buffer.
            read = fStream.Read(buffer, 0, toRead)
        Loop

        fStream.Close()
    End Using
```

Comment: You need to start with something to get help here. Have you tried anything? If so, add the code to the question and state an actual problem. If not, SO is not the right forum for you.

Comment: I searched through google, to get started but could not find something   I can use to get started, I downloaded odbc driver of dbisam but it is not showing in my Windows odbc DataSources, so, I am not able to use tables from odbc data sources too.

Comment: What I am saying here is that you are not likely to get any help at all with this question here. You'll have to find another forum or rephrase you question. http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: I have edited question hope this time is useful

Comment: this is not easy to answer: WHICH product/Technology is used by the accounting Software? Personally, I know at least the following "ISAM" implementations: Tsunami Record Manager, Btrieve (up to 6.x), VsamEx (the successor of isamdb for vb) and ESENT. Not mentioned the myisam and old Cobol isam files ...

Comment: it is Sam4 POS, it is build in Delphi and DBisam 4, and it stores data files in .dat format